# How to prevent JPA query related entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Firstly, let me thank to who want to give the answer,

I am a new person using JPA for now, suppose that I have two tables, table A and B, for table A, we have the column

id_A,
id_B,
etc...

For table B, we have
id_B

And we have the entity classes,

```
@Data
class A {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_A")
    private String id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_B", referencedColumnName = "ID_B")
    private B b;
}

@Data
class B {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_B")
    private String id;
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @BatchSize(size = BATCH_SIZE)
    private List<A> as;
}
```

Now, in order to only use the id of B, I firstly select all the relevant entity of A by ARepository.findAllByIds().

with the above query, I want to get all the ID_Bs, but when I do it by looping the result of the above query - a.getB, I noticed that it will get the B from Database again.

I know that we can fetch the A and B together by EAGER or EntityGraph, etc...

I am just wondering, is there any a way that I can only get the id_b from the ARepository.findAllByIds()?

Comment: N+1 queries problem sounds familiar? Either you will do 2 queries (one for all As and then one for all Bs and join them in the memory) or you will do one query using fetch join on As.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question I think you will have to annotate your findAllByIds method with something like...

`@Query(value = "SELECT a, b.id FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.b b where a.id in :ids")` then your Bs will be loaded within the same query as the As